Cross-platform (Windows/Linux) alternatives to FileZilla?
Does anyone have recommendations for a cross-platform (particularly one with Windows and Linux builds, not requiring the use of WINE on Linux) alternative to FileZilla?  I'd like it to have a similar UI (panes on the left and right to browse the local and remote file systems in one window).  The reason I don't want to use FileZilla is that for some reason, the latest version seems to be very buggy (some really fundamental bugs that are often regressions) that are getting no attention for months and months, probably related to the fact that the developers are apparently too stubborn to switch from SVN to Git which would make it easier to contribute fixes for many people, myself included.

From personal experience with Filezilla, I used the last version for a while and ended up bringing the backup with the old installer and now I'm using an earlier version that's better than the latest. Once it works well, no reason to switch.

As of today, there's nothing even remotely close to FileZilla that works on both systems. Not to mention free and open source. This app has been dominating that niche for years now.
You might want to start looking into plugins - for browsers, IDEs, etc. The most robust one I can think of would be FireFTP. Which kind of even looks similarly to FileZilla, but of course has limited functionality. It's also not updated anymore.

There's nothing even remotely close to FileZilla That's a claim ultimately very difficult to prove true. Even if you've not found it yourself, it doesn't means it doesn't exist. [edited by mods to tone it down a bit & to fix a typo]

You can prove that within another answer. I stated what I believe is true and that's it. [edited by mods for civility... please keep things friendly]
